Could parents' LLCs be used as a loophole in US federal child labor laws?
I came across this link: US Department of Labor - Fair Labor Standards Act Advisor
It says:

The Fair Labor Standards Act (FLSA) sets 14 as the minimum age for most non-agricultural work. However, at any age, youth may deliver newspapers; perform in radio, television, movie, or theatrical productions; work in businesses owned by their parents (except in mining, manufacturing or hazardous jobs)

I'm wondering if this language would allow parents to have their children work for a small LLC or something run by the parents, while doing work on behalf of that LLC for an external company that is indistinguishable from the work of a full-time employee at that company.
Example 1
A 12 year old is at a coworking space or at home, sitting next to his software-engineer father, working on a laptop, doing programming or project-management work for the same company that his father is employed by (with whatever intermediary legal entities and procedural workarounds might be necessary to make it legal).
Example 2

Pam is going on maternity leave again, so Dunder Mifflin needs a temporary receptionist. It offers the job to her daughter, Cecelia, who is 12.
Toby reminds them that this would be a violation of federal child-labor laws and proposes a workaround:

Pam creates a single-member LLC called Temps R Us.
Temps R Us hires Cecelia.
Dunder Mifflin contracts with Temps R Us to provide staffing services
Temps R Us assigns Cecelia to work the Dunder Mifflin job as a receptionist until Pam returns.
Dunder Mifflin pays Temps R Us for sending a person to fill the role; Temps R Us uses that money to give Cecelia her allowance.


Are either Dunder Mifflin or Temps R Us in violation of child-labor laws?

It isn't a loophole, it is written there explicitly. I knew lots of kids who worked for businesses owned by their parents. This isn't new.

@JonCuster I think the intent of this question is regarding children, who, while working for their parents business, are then hired on as contractors with other businesses.

@nick012000 - unclear - that last sentence to me still ties the children to what their parents are themselves doing.

@JonCuster nick012000 was correct, I was asking about children doing work indistinguishable from full-time office employees at some larger company, while technically being employed by their parents' LLC.

Fair enough. I suspect that such a situation would fail the intent of the Act since the work is being performed at the company - they are not working "in" a business owned by their parents. The company contracting the person would have the liability of having an underaged child performing work at their site.

@JonCuster right but what if the child was working remotely from their parents' house or a coworking space or something like that?

You should probably read the act itself, not just this brief summary. Also, as that site mentions, individual states may have more strict laws, and they take precedence. If the act isn't specific, there may be DoL policies and court precedents.

Even if contract work is becoming more common, much of that increase is probably from gig work, which children would often not be eligible for (you need a driver's license to be an Uber driver, although you could deliver GrubHub on a bicycle). I'll bet this has been tested in the past.

@NathanWailes I think I understand your question, but also why others aren't clear on it. I've added an example that I think might capture the problem. Feel free to reject it if I'm off-base.

1099’s are a distraction, the children would not be 1099 employees, they would be W2 employees. The parents would not be 1099 either, they would be being paid as corporations of some soRT.

@bdb484 I think your example is along the lines of what I'm imagining, but I was imagining them in a permanent position, not just a temporary one. I was imagining a 12yo at a coworking space or at home, sitting next to his father, working on a laptop, doing programming/project-management work for the same employer as his father (with whatever intermediary legal entities and procedural workarounds that might be necessary to make it legal).


I'm wondering if this language would allow parents to have their children work as contractors for a small LLC or something run by their parent

Contractors don't work in someone's business, they work for someone's business, but in their own business. "Working in business owned by their parents" means being that business' employee.

while doing work for an external company that is indistinguishable from that of a full-time employee at that company.

That again runs afoul of contractor determination laws. See the IRS:

You are not an independent contractor if you perform services that can be controlled by an employer (what will be done and how it will be done).

See also the FLSA rules on classifying contractors vs. employees.
and for a State law example - California:

Under the ABC test, a worker is considered an employee and not an independent contractor, unless the hiring entity satisfies all three of the following conditions:

The worker is free from the control and direction of the hiring entity in connection with the performance of the work, both under the contract for the performance of the work and in fact;
The worker performs work that is outside the usual course of the hiring entity’s business; and
The worker is customarily engaged in an independently established trade, occupation, or business of the same nature as that involved in the work performed.



I don't think you're understanding the OP's scenario. Imagine a construction contracting business. They have construction workers as employees, and they send them out on jobs to businesses that hire the construction company.

@Barmar doesn't matter really, FLSA also has rules on who's contractor vs. employee (I probably should have quoted that instead of the IRS), but the point is - if the parents are the employers then it's fine, if not - then not. Statutory, constructive, or actual - either way. The scenario you're describing is not a "loophole", the scenario in the question is - that's also the scenario typically used to reclassify employees as contractors, and that the State laws and the Federal rules are trying to crack down on.

@littleadv Sorry, I didn't word my question carefully enough. I'm asking if there's any arrangement that would make it legal for children to work part/full-time doing work that people typically associate with needing to be 18+ (like white-collar / office work), even if it means using intermediate legal entities (like an LLC run by the parents) or other procedural workarounds like doing the work remotely.

Well, remote work would follow the remote location labor laws, whatever they are. Basically shifting liability by reclassifying employees as contractors is what you're asking about (whatever that liability is - child labor, benefits, minimum wages, what's not). So that's what I was addressing.
